# How do I mock a realine of a GLOB ref when unit testing in perl?

Tags: unit-testing, perl

For example in the following code how do I mock readline to unit test the do_stuff routine?

I think I require

1. $sock must be a GLOB reference.
2. readline() must be mocked.

I tried using FileHandle->new but got error - "readline() on unopened filehandle GEN1"
which I took as readline() wasn't being mocked.

I tried an Test::MockObject (not extends), with readline() mocked, but that had the error
"Not a GLOB reference" which reminded me that readline() isn't being called as a method.

```
package MyIO;

sub get_sock{ return IO::Socket::INET->new(@tcp_arg); }

sub do_stuff {
    my $sock = get_sock();
    my $line1 = <$sock>;
    my $line2 = readline($sock);
    return;
}

package TestMyIO;

sub test_do_stuff{
    # my $mock_sock = Test::MockObject::Extends->new(IO::Socket::INET->new);

    my $mock_sock = die("TODO");
    my @fake_lines = ('line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3');

    no warnings 'redefine';    ## no critic (ProhibitNoWarnings)
    local *MyIO::get_sock = sub { return $mock_sock; };
    local *MyIO::readline = sub { return shift @fake_lines; };
    use warnings 'redefine';

}
```

Comment: Note that `<$sock>` is *identical* to `readline($sock)`

Comment: Please consider up-voting the question. I put in research effort and clearly described the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```perl
open(my $fh, '<', \$str);
```

This won't work if a system file handle is needed (e.g. if the handle needs to survive an `exec`). But as long as you stick to Perl, reads from the handle will read from the provided buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Builtins like `readline` must be mocked in the `CORE::GLOBAL` namespace, and must generally be defined at compile-time.

```
my @fake_lines;
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::readline = sub { shift @fake_lines };
}
@fake_lines = ('line 1','line 2','line 3');
```